# Why can't I change the name of my edit function?

Tags: php, laravel

I have some posts on my index page, and each post has an edit button on it.
The problem is, I want the URL to be hungarian, but every time I change the function's name from edit to sth. else it gives me 404 error.

I show the posts with the following code:

```
@foreach($posts as $post)
     <div class="card p-3">
             <h3><a href="/elado/{{$post->id}}">{{$post->title}}</a></h3>
           <small>Feltöltve: {{$post->created_at}}</small>
         <h3><a href="/elado/{{$post->id}}/edit">Szerkesztés</a></h3> I TRY TO CHANGE /EDIT TO STH. ELSE HERE
     </div>
@endforeach
```

And here is my posts controller with the edit function:

```
public function edit($id) { I change edit here as well
        $post = Post::find($id);
        return view('elado.szerkeszt')->with('post', $post);
    }
```

In web.php, I've

```
Route::resource('elado', 'PostsController');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you're using `resource()` method in your route declaration. Which will use by default there routes and control methods

```php
[
    'create',
    'store',
    'show',
    'edit',
    'update',
    'destroy',
]
```

If you want to change the method name, declare the route on your own

```php
Route::post('/change', 'PostsController@change');
```

Comment: I've tried it already, but `Route::post('/szerkeszt', 'PostsController@szerkeszt');` and changing the method name to 'szerkeszt' has not worked.

Comment: @O.Collins can you add your a bigger chunk of your route file in your question ? you can also run the command `php artisan route:list` to check if the route is declared properly.

Comment: Well, I found the solution. I had to change the route to the full "url pattern" like this `Route::get('elado/{elado}/szerkeszt', 'PostsController@szerkeszt');` and had to change from post to get as well.

Comment: However, `php artisan route:list` helped me to find this, thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can exclude edit method from resource routes with except method like, then define new route with your custom edit method and put before resources routes:

```
Route::post('/elado/{id}', 'PostsController@sth');

Route::resource('elado', 'PostsController')->except([
        'edit'
    ]);
```